# Unity tells me to reference through an instance of an object, Visual Studio tells me not to

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference, instance, nullreferenceexception

so I'm creating a save and load script, here's it's content:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SaveLoad : MonoBehaviour {

public Player player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player> ();

public void Save() {

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("X", transform.position.x);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Y", transform.position.y);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Z", transform.position.z);

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Health", Player.Health.CurrentVal);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Exp", Player.Exp.CurrentVal);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Oxygen", Player.Oxygen.CurrentVal);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PlayerLevel", Player.PlayerLevel.CurrentVal);

    Debug.Log ("Saved");


}

public void Load() {
    float x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("X");
    float y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Y");
    float z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Z");

    Player.Health.CurrentVal = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Health");
    Player.Exp.CurrentVal = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Exp");
    Player.Oxygen.CurrentVal = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Oxygen");
    Player.PlayerLevel.CurrentVal = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("PlayerLevel");

    transform.position = new Vector3 (x, y, z);

    Debug.Log ("Loaded");
}
}
```

The first version, without the "public Player player" line, returned a NullReferenceException and said to reference through an instance of an object in Unity. Now when I try to do that(instead of ("Health", Player.Health.CurrentVal) i use("Health", player.Health.CurrentVal), without capital in "Player", refering to the instance I creaded in the same script), Visual tells me "Player.Health cannot be accessed with an instance of an object; qualify it with a type name instead". As you can see, I'm kinda stuck in a loop here. Did I mess up with trying to get player as an instance? It's also a little bit of a mess cause Player is both the gameobject's name and the script's.
Player script:

```
[SerializeField] public Stat health;
public static Stat Health { get; set; }
[SerializeField] private Stat exp;
public static Stat Exp { get; set; }
[SerializeField] private Stat oxygen;
public static Stat Oxygen { get; set; }
[SerializeField] private Stat playerLevel;
public static Stat PlayerLevel { get; set; }
[SerializeField] private Text playerLevelText;
```

And here's the Stat custom variable class:

```
[SerializeField] private BarPrototype bar;
[SerializeField] private float maxVal;
[SerializeField] private float currentVal;

public float CurrentVal 
{
    get 
    {
        return currentVal;
    }
    set 
    {
        this.currentVal = Mathf.Clamp (value, 0, MaxVal);
        if( bar != null )
            bar.Value = this.currentVal;
    }
}
```

SerializeField is used just to access those values from inspector.

Comment: Could you post relevant part from `Player` class?

Comment: Sure, see the first post @botond.botos

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you can't initialize public members like this:

```
public Player player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player> ();
```

They should be initialized in Start, Awake or OnEnable method. If you change it to below it should work

```
public Player player;
void Start(){
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player> ();
}
```

Another thing is why should you make it public then? If assigned in inspector then its assigned value would be ignored after Start(). I suggest you make it internal. or to be safe:

```
public Player player;
void Start(){
    if(player == null)
       player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player> ();
}
```

Comment: "Now when I try to do that(instead of ("Health", Player.Health.CurrentVal) i use("Health", player.Health.CurrentVal), without capital in "Player", refering to the instance I creaded in the same script), Visual tells me "Player.Health cannot be accessed with an instance of an object; qualify it with a type name instead"."

Unity also tells me I should put "public Player player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player> ();" in a Start() method, I'm going to see where this leads me in a sec.

Comment: When I try to do that, Visual Studio doesn't recognize } as closing of Start method, what it does instead is it closes the SaveLoad class with it and messes up the rest of the script :/

Comment: I edited the answer. the reason it still gives you that same error is you have other errors in script and unity did not compile your changes. both changes should be made in order to take effect

Comment: @Nech Ok. I missed the static members part sorry about that. I updated the answer. the first way you accessed Health etc. was ok.